# Riemann mapping theorem (Statement/Proof)

Tags: complex-analysis

For a test I have to be able to state and prove the Riemann Mapping Theorem. In my lecture notes, the proof is very, very long. Continues over two pages. I wanted to ask if anybody knows where to look for a shorter proof?

Comment: I think you should study the proof you have been given in your lectures.

Comment: Two pages isn't long. You're not going to find anything shorter. Just try to learn and understand it.

Answer (score 0):

The Riemann mapping theorem is a pinnacle of the theory of complex analysis in one variable, and it's unreasonable to expect that there is a very short proof.

However, depending on how you set things up, it shouldn't be too bad. If you know about normal families, the standard proof is reasonably straight-forward once you have understood the main ideas.